# Can Someone Walk Me Through How to Playback Midi files from 3.5 disk on Casio Celviano AL-100 R

Tags: keyboard, software

I have the above captioned digital piano.  I would like to play back midi files from the computer on the piano.  How do I do this?

Comment: I'm sure this would be e better question for Casio's customer support site.

Answer (score 0):

you hook up a midi cable from pc's midiout to keyboard's midiin (or usb cable if that's how your keyboard connects midi) and use "midi sequencer" software.  also called "digital audio workstation" (DAW) software.  Which one?  That is a decision you need to research cuz there are tons and tons of em.  And nobody will want to help you including me :(

But it's no different for that keyboard than any other keyboard.  Well there are differences in control changes and sounds.  But any sequencer or daw software will do that.

Good luck :)

Oh just saw the 3.5" disk thing.  Unless the keyboard has a disk drive for em, you're gonna have to get the midi files off of that archaic format onto your PC.  If it DOES have a disk drive, you're gonna have to go to the manufacturer's website, download the manual, and read for days until you figure it out.  Again, nobody will want to help you with that including me :)

Sorry, but that's life...